# android xml drawable half height

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So I am trying to achieve that the layer shape takes axact the half of the height.
this is how it looks: [image]

I want the white and the green to take exact the half of the height this is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="50dip">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:top="50dip">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="50dip">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"></solid>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:right="150dip">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change last item android:right attribute

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this.

```
<item android:left="50dip">
    <layer-list>
        <item >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:height="350dip">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"></solid>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:right="150dip">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Please elaborate _what_ your code changes and _why_ you think it is what OP is looking for.

Comment: this is yet a fixed sized not the half of the height ;)

Comment: you want green and white half size so you can change the height of the item as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean half of the height of the screen you can't change it in the XML but rather in the code like so and it will update when the application runs:

```
//Getting the height of the screen
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.green_shape);
gradientDrawable.setBounds(0,0, 0, height/2); //setbottom bound to be half of the height
```

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="50dip">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"></solid>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:id="@+id/green_shape">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"></solid>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:right="150dip">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```